# Monogame - Generating a tile map

Tags: c#, .net, xna, monogame

I'm creating a 2D game and I want to be able to **draw tiles** to create my game world. I have created a `List` like so:

```
static private List<Rectangle> tiles = new List<Rectangle>();

public const int TileWidth = 50;
public const int TileHeight = 50;

public static void initialise(Texture2D tileTexture)
{
        texture = tileTexture;
        tiles.Clear();

        tiles.Add(new Rectangle(0, 267, TileWidth, TileHeight));
        tiles.Add(new Rectangle(1575,795, TileWidth, TileHeight));
        tiles.Add(new Rectangle(1315,267, TileWidth, TileHeight));
        tiles.Add(new Rectangle(1051,797, TileWidth, TileHeight));
    }
```

I'm trying to generate tiles into my game world in a way that allows me to manually choose where I place each tile using an **array**, however I'm having some difficulty with this.

Comment: Be a bit more explicit, describe your problem and show what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

I´m guessing you want a double array for the tiles? I´m gonna go ahead and make some guesses on what it is you are trying to achieve here.

Maybe something like this:

```
private static Rectangle[][] tiles;
private const int worldWidth = 50;
private const int worldDepth = 50;

public static void Initialize(Texture2D tileTexture)
{
    // Initialize game table
    tiles = new Rectangle[worldWidth][];
    for (int l = 0; l < worldWidth; l++)
    {
        tiles[l] = new Rectangle[worldDepth];
    }

    // Fill rectangles in for every tile
    for(int i = 0; i < worldWidth; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < worldDepth; k++)
        {
            // Tile (0,0): x = 0, y = 0
            // Tile (0,1): x = 0, y = 50
            // and so on...
            tiles[i][k] = new Rectangle(i * TileWidth, k * TileHeight, TileWidth, TileHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

There are probably better ways of doing this but this is a simple solution and should be easy to understand.

Comment: Yes I've created a list of rectangles named "tiles" saving the location of my tiles from a sprite sheet I have. I would like to draw the tiles with a 2d array but only on certain parts of the map, as I'm aiming for a dungeon crawler / maze style. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can draw list of rectangles like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < tiles.Count(); i++)
    spriteBatch.Draw(tileImage, tiles[i], Color.White);
```

Please provide more information on your errors / struggles and I will provide better answer.